# Как запустить мою программу при открытии ссылки в браузере?

Tags: c#, url

Есть программа, нужно сделать ссылку для неё, например, как у Steam: `steam://open/friends`. Она должна открываться в браузере и запускать нужное мне окно; Подскажите, как это делается, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Я буду объяснять на примере другой программы – sales logix (аббревиатура - slx), она регистрирует свой протокол `slx://` например, ссылка может быть такой: `slx://account/12345`.

Штука реально крутая: можно было по почте кинуть такую ссылку коллеге и у него по клику на линке открывалось приложение с окном по клиента ID=12345.

Если вы хотите создать собственный протокол – то вам нужно две вещи сделать:

- зарегистрировать протокол в операционной системе и программу, которая его будет обрабатывать;
- прописать в программе обработку протокола.

По [этой ссылке](http://www.slxdeveloper.com/page.aspx?action=viewarticle&articleid=80) вам предлагают вариант регистрации протокола через правку реестра (и так удобнее в корпоративном мире – раскатать reg-файл по нужным компам политиками Active Directory, чем руками ходить каждый настраивать), но если очень хочется без магии реестра и руками – то где-то в панели управления есть пункт типа "программы по умолчанию".

Копирую пример reg-файла, на случай если линк протухнет:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\slx]
@="SalesLogix Protocol Handler"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\slx\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\SalesLogix\\salesLogix.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\slx\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\slx\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\slx\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\SalesLogix\\SalesLogixUrlLink.exe\" %1"
```

Ну и нужно собственно в своей программе сделать поддержку этого протокола.

Я думаю, что это абсолютно понятно, как сделать – в каждой программе есть метод Main:

```
static void Main(string[] param)
```

Вам нужно парсить переданные аргументы командной строки и, в соответствии с вашей логикой обрабатывать.

Если на компьютере будет установлена программа и зарегистрирован протокол, то вызываться будет и с веб-страники, и из почты. Можно даже в ярлыки эту ссылку вписывать, как это делает стим – и тоже будет работать.

Update. Передаваемая ссылка будет в args[0] целиком, парсить её нужно будет самостоятельно, отделяя протокол. Тест тривиальный:

В c:\temp\proba01.exe:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var ar in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} = {ar}");
            i++;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Делаем обработчик:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\s2x]
@="SalesLogix Protocol Handler"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\s2x\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\temp\\proba01.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\s2x\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\s2x\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\s2x\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\temp\\proba01.exe\" %1"
```

Демо-страница:

```
<html>

    <body>
        <a href="s2x://account/123">test</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе имеем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как параметры обработать не совсем понятно, можете дополнить? Допустим был вызов `slx://account/12345` и что? у меня в `param[0]` окажется `account` и в `param[1]` окажется `12345`? Или как?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Хм, а вот таких деталей я уже не помню, мне кажется, что в param[0] окажется весь `account/12345`. Я уточню вечером и допишу в ответ.

Comment: Буду ждать пинга

Comment: @АндрейNOP Проекта под рукой нет, поэтому просто собрал лёгкое приложение. Итог - в args[0] попадает полностью строка с протоколом (видимо, чтобы можно было писать приложение, которое поддерживает несколько протоколов), подробности вписал в вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо! Значит просто можно загрузить в `Uri` и разобрать с помощью него

Comment: @АндрейNOP Таки да, Uri вам в .Scheme прекрасно отдаст имя вашего кастомного протокола, .Host отдаст 'account' ну и так далее.

Comment: А под Linux так можно сделать?