# Как сделать чтобы при открытии файла в своей программе то он открылся автоматически

Tags: c#, winforms

Здраствуйте, я зделал учебную программу на winform c#.net, со своим типом файла (.sp) и выбрал открывать эти файлы этой программой, но когда я открыл этот файл там била стартовая страница. Как сделать чтобы этот файл открылся в програмне автоматически.

Comment: [Почитайте это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759317/220553), думаю полностью ответит на поставленный вами вопрос.

Comment: Для этого ваша программа должна уметь читать и понимать параметры командной строки, потому что то, что вы назвали "открыл этот файл", судя по всему двойным кликом, преобразуется в консольную команду `MyProgram.exe MyFile.sp`

Comment: простите я не совсем понимаю как это сделать помогите пожалуста

Comment: т.к. я не знаю как у вас организована загрузка файла через интерфейс (скорее всего весь код в обработчике события формы, в противном случае я буду приятно удивлен), то ни чего кроме ссылки на пример работы с параметрами командной строки, которую уже дали, предложить не могу. Ваше приложение должно учитывать возможность передачи файла через командную строку на уровне его архитектуры. Т.е. сначала нужно сделать чтобы программа работала через командную строку, и только потом через визуальный интерфейс.