# Можно ли запустить .exe файл с браузера?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js

Всем  привет, подскажите, можно ли реализовать такую функцию:

На сайте пользователь в личном кабинете указывает путь к файлу .exe на своем ПК -> сохраняем этот путь -> Запускаем .exe файл

Своего рода лаунчер, только Web.
Такой когда был у 4game

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Браузер не имеет таких методов. Можно разве что написать приложение на `Electron` и завернуть личный кабинет в него и запускать `exe` как и хотелось.

Comment: Зависит от браузера. Можно в некоторые версиях IE.

Answer (score 0):

На прямую из браузера таких действий выполнить невозможно, все что происходит в браузере выполняется в своем роде песочнице. Но тут на ум приходит связки как у utorrent, telegram, skype и тд. Нажимаешь на кнопку и открывается приложение...

Возможно, эта ссылка будет полезна в решении вашей задачи : [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759297/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5/759317)

Но опять же без дополнительного ПО тут не обойтись.