# Сбор всех ссылок в HTML документе

Tags: html, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста, хочу собрать все ссылки из HTML документа.

Если я правильно понимаю, то сбор ссылок нужно начинать с нахождения атрибута href тега `<a>`.

Если да, то подскажите, как определить, что в href - указано относительная или абсолютная ссылка?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что:

- Абсолютная ссылка - ВСЕГДА - будет начинаться или с "http://", "https://", "www."

И по этому критерию можно будет отличить - относительно ссылку от абсолютной ?

Comment: Верно, абсолютная ссылка должна начинаться с представленных Вами вариантов + так можно будет отличить её от относительной. В таком случае есть встречный вопрос: можно ли (и нужно ли) использовать сторонние ЯП вроде PHP?

Comment: @4500zenja, Спасибо! Насчет ЯП, то только С/С++.

Comment: Не соглашусь с @4500zenja. Вот спецификация https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt , вариантов куча (ftp, magnet, file, ed2k и много других). Более того - можно создать собственные варианты (например zoom и citrix). Вот еще пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759297/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5

Comment: @UserTest013, Спасибо. Все оказалось куда сложнее, чем казалось в начале :(

Comment: И еще... Вероятно атрибута href будет не достаточно, не знаю вашей цели, но ссылки могут быть и в атрибуте action тегов form и button. Ну и js может ссылки создавать/открывать

Answer (score 1):

Если рассматривать возможность применения регулярных выражений, то можно будет использовать регулярное выражение следующего вида.

```regex
<a\b[^>]+?href=["'][a-z]+://[^>]+>
```

Данное регулярное выражение поможет найти только открывающий тег `<a>` целиком.

В данном регулярном выражении:

- `\b` — граница слова. Что бы целевым тегом считался только тег `<a>`
- `[^>]+?` — будут выбираться все не `>` символы. Ленивая выборка. Выборка остановится при совпадении следующей части выражения
- `["']` — один из двух допустимых символов в которые можно *обворачивать* значение
- `[a-z]+://` — нахождение sсhema-части URL в начале значения атрибута `href`

Comment: Спасибо, но регулярки тут излишни, хотя можно и ими. Найти начало тега <a> или Сразу подстроку href=" - без регулярок не проблема и выделить, то, что находится в "...", вопрос в том, как интерпретировать этот "URL".

Comment: @Optimus1, как вариант — просто проверять на нахождение `://` в полученном `...`. Если действие качается касается URL, то в абсолютных URL без этой части никуда.