# Как запускать программу при открытии файла

Tags: c#, decode, lzw

Хочу чтобы запускалась программа для декодирования информации из файла с моим расширением.
Если имеет значение, то прогаю на `C#`, сжимаю с помощью `LZW` алгоритма.

Comment: Нужно зарегистрировать расширение в системе. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69761/12888024

Comment: А как производить данное действия на пк других пользователей, когда они установят это ПО

Comment: Вы дочитайте до конца

Comment: ну или https://stackoverflow.com/a/2697804/312041

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759317/220553

Comment: Придумайте только уникальное расширение, чтобы не пересекалось с какими-то известными.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)