Как зарегистрировать свою программу в качестве FTP-клиента
Требуется, чтобы по ссылкам типа ftp://что-то, из браузеров в Windows открывалась моя программа, а не вопрос типа в чём открыть без возможности выбрать что-то кроме браузера.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759317/220553

Забыл уточнить, на свой нестандартный протокол я  по этой статье научился это делать) Но система, из которой я пытаюсь это делать не позволяет ничего кроме стандартных http, ftp, mailto, просто рубит ссылки. А вот стандартные протоколы таким методом не получается переназначить, винда не даёт. На моё счастье был ещё неиспользуемый skype, на который и получилось переназначить.
